# When are thermodynamical potentials conserved?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential-energy

I have studied that are 4 thermodynamical potentials wich are useful, which are the internal energy $U$, the helmholtz function $F$, the Gibbs free energy $G$ and the enthalpy $H$:

$$dU=TdS-PdV$$
$$dH=TdS+VdP$$
$$dG=VdP-SdT$$
$$dF=-SdT-PdV$$

where, $T$ is temperature, $S$ is entropy, $V$ volume and $P$ pressure. But when do we know that these processes are conserved? For example I know (and is somehow intuitive) that in an isolated system internal energy has to be conserved. But what about the others?

Comment: Entropy is conserved in reversible processes taking place in an isolated system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's write the complete form of these differentials:

**Energy** $dU = T dS - P dV + \mu dN$: To get $dU = 0$ we must set $dS=0$, $dV=0$, $dN=0$. This means *adiabatic*+*constant volume*+*closed*.

**Enthalpy** $dH = T dS + V dP + \mu dN$: To get $dH=0$ set $dS=0$, $dP=0$, $dN=0$. This means *adiabatic*+*isobaric*+*closed*.

**Gibbs energy** $dG = -S dT+V dP + \mu dN$. To get $dG=0$ set $dT=0$, $dP=0$, $dN=0$. This means *isothermal*+*isobaric*+*closed*

**Free energy** $dF = - SdT - P dV + \mu dN$: The get $dF=0$ set $dT=0$, $dV=0$, $dN=0$. This means *isothermal*+*constant-volume*+*closed*.

Not much memorization needed if you just follow the rules of calculus.

Comment: I don't think I ever saw $\mu dN$. What is it? Other than that good answer

Comment: $\mu$ is the chemical potential. The internal energy is a function of entropy, volume, and number of particles. When we write $dU = TdS - P dV$, we imply a closed system, i.e., $dN=0$. If we allow $N$ to change, then the full form of the differential is the one I gave above. Sam with all other potentials.